# Is it possible to downgrade .NET Framework from version 4.8 to 4.7.2

Tags: windows, .net-framework, downgrade

I need to downgrade .net framework from 4.8 to 4.7.2 in order to test some software.  I've read in forums like this one that .net framework is a feature now in Windows server 2008 r2.  That said can this feature be downgraded and updated anymore?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to downgrade .NET framework from 4.8 to 4.7.2 in order to test some software.

The .NET Framework is backwards compatible with itself.  If you have .NET Framework 4.8 installed on a system then it's possible to run any .NET 4.7.2 application.

> I've read in forums like this one that .NET framework is a feature now in Windows server 2008 r2.

Windows Server 2008 R2 is based on Windows Vista, only modern supported versions of Windows and Windows Server, have .NET Framework built-in.  The version that can be enabled through the Windows Features on Windows Server 2008 R2 is .NET Framework 3.0.  .NET Framework 3.0 cannot run .NET Framework 4.0+ applications due to the Common Language Runtime differences.

> That said can this feature be downgraded and updated anymore?

.NET Framework 4.7.2 does not actually support Windows Server 2008 R2.  You will be unable to install .NET Framework 4.7.2 on a system that is running Windows Server 2008 R2.